# U-Haul rental cruiser bike information?

Tags: vintage

[image]Anyone know anything about this U-Haul bike?  I got it at the wreckers before they crushed it. It was just the frame brakes and forks. I added the rest.

[image: Photo of U-Haul bike]

Comment: That's a nice bit of work.  What do the letters stamped into the chainring spell ?  (helpful for search engines)

Comment: The original chainring was severely damaged, I'm in the process of trying to fix it. The  chainring/crank/pedals/seat on it now is from an older (late 70's) CCM . Works great. The rims are aluminum.  It's a long frame, If it don't sell I thinking of painting it, adding a springer front end, banana seat, high risers and a 4 speed nexus rear hub with suicide shifter and white walls.

Comment: I've removed the small pricing bit, because costs are so variable and highly regionalised, valuations are "off topic"  There's some great info in the answers given here, and its a neat piece of history.  Good work saving it from the scrap.

Answer (score 8):

**Bike Information**
Here's a [thread on the acquisition and rehabilitation](https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=747617) of a U-Haul cruiser.

Summary:

> I saw the UHAUL stamping on the BB, the Made in Taiwan gold decal, and the FBC stamp on the rear dropout. With a little research and help from forum members it was determined that its an early to mid 80's Taiwanese built bicycle specifically for UHAUL.

[image]

Evidently U-Haul had special made bicycles to rent.
Since they were "Not To Be Sold" one might wonder how they wound up in the wild.

Another [thread with informative](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/fbc-u-haul-cruiser.142330/) pictures.

Key Information

> FBC is Fit bicycle company, 1990’s pre China made in Taiwan.

Fully restored
[image]
[bmxmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/forsale/300518)

> In the early 1980's U-Haul ordered X amount of these bikes from FBC (not Fit Bike Co) so they could be used as rentals. They are stamped UHAUL on bottom bracket and FBC on rear dropout. There are only 3 known survivors in the USA currently out of 4 that have surfaced in the last decade. When it was new the bike was originally equipped with a Shimano 333 3-speed hub, bear trap style pedals, MX caliper brakes, 7X rims, Snakebelly tires, chrome cruiser bars, and a Persons spring seat like the one on Pee Wee Herman's bike.

**Bike Value**
We don't offer valuations.
A bike is worth what someone will pay for it. Since that changes over time the information becomes out of date. We hope to provide information that does not go stale.

Comment: Many thanks for the info. Sounds like I got lucky to get one.